# Dynamically Selecting Embedded Image For A List Based on data result from SQLite

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have a Spark list which needs different images loaded into it based on data coming through from an SQlite query.

In SQLite I have a column called "IconId" which for example might contain the value "1", "2", "3" etc representing an icon image.

My Icon images are Embedded in a class called "ImageResources" as follows:

```
[Bindable]
public class ImageResources
{

[Embed(source="../assets/caticons/icon1.jpg")]
    public static var Ic1Cla:Class;

[Embed(source="../assets/caticons/icon2.jpg")]
    public static var Ic2Cla:Class;
}
```

Then I have the itemrenderer for my Spark List which has a Bitmap which I use to set the icon I want to use for the list item like this.. This is a static example which works:

```
<s:BitmapImage source="{ImageResources.Ic1Cla}"   
         x="5" y="2">

</s:BitmapImage>
```

My question is..Can I dynamically concatenate the BitmapImage source somehow to something that will take the number coming from my SQLite data e.g "1" into something like this:

```
<s:BitmapImage source="{ImageResources.Ic[data.IconId]Cla}"   
         x="5" y="2">

</s:BitmapImage>
```

Obviously this doesn't work but I'm not sure if it's a simple syntax issue or whether it could even be done in this manner.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically access a variable such as:

```
<s:BitmapImage source="{ImageResources['Ic' + data.IconId + 'Cla']}" />
```

There are other approaches, such as using a state system.  By setting the current state as in `currentState = "image" + data.IconId;` this could be implemented as:

```
<s:states>
    <s:State name="image1" />
    <s:State name="image2" />
</s:states>

<s:BitmapImage source.image1="{ImageResources.Ic1Cla}"
               source.image2="{ImageResources.Ic2Cla}" />
```

Comment: Perfect! Thankyou very much Jason. Your top method works. I have trouble with syntax being a complete beginner and all :)